# Fermi Golden Rule: Why interaction picture is fundamental for proving it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, interactions, time-evolution, fermis-golden-rule

Sakurai and Wikipedia proove the golden rule in the *interaction picture*. As the reason of that choice is not clear for me, I ask you what are the difficulties that rise up when you try to get the rule in the Shrodinger picture.
It appears that there are no difficulties, but the result you get is different (and that is physically meaningless).

Here I show what happens in the Schrodinger picture.
I also stress that it is relevant to understand where this proof is wrong, in order to understand why it is easier to work in the interaction picture!

If the system is in the eigenstate $|n \rangle$ of $H_0$ at time $t=0$, the coefficient of state $|m \rangle$ at time $t$ is $c_m(t) = \langle m|U(t)|n \rangle$ where $U(t)$ is the time evolution operator.
As Schrodinger equation can be written as $\dot{U} = -iU$ ($\hbar = 1$), we can express $U(t)$ as its *Dyson series*
$$U(t) = 1 - {i}\int_0^tdt'H(t') + ({-i})^2\int_0^tH(t')dt'\int_0^{t'}dt'' H(t'') + ...$$
Where the omitted terms are $o(t^2)$.

So
$$c_m(t) = \langle m|U(t)|n \rangle = c_{m}^{(0)}(t) + c_{m}^{(1)}(t) + c_{m}^{(2)}(t) + o(t^2)$$
where the first coefficients of the sum are
$$c_{m}^{(0)}(t) = \langle m|1|n \rangle = \delta_{m,n}$$
$$c_{m}^{(1)}(t) = -i\int_0^tdt'\langle m|H(t')|n \rangle = -i\int_0^tdt'\langle m|H_0 + V(t')|n \rangle = 
$$
$$= -i\int_0^tdt'e^{i(E_n-E_m)t'}\delta_{n,m} -i\int_0^tdt'V_{m,n}(t') $$
and $V_{n,l}(t) = \langle n|V(t)|l\rangle$, where $V$ is the interaction term in the *Shrodinger picture*.

As we are interested in scatterings, we consider $m\neq n$, so $c_m^{(0)}=0$ and the *first order approximation* of $|c_m(t)|^2$ is

$$|c_m(t)|^2 \simeq |c_m^{(1)}|^2 = |\int_0^tdt'V_{m,n}(t')|^2$$

This result is **incompatible** with the one you can find in many books, working in the interaction picture
$$|c_m(t)|^2 \simeq |c_m^{(1)}|^2 = |\int_0^tdt'e^{i(E_m-E_n)t'}V_{m,n}(t')|^2$$

Where the exponential in the integral is *fundamental* to get the famous delta in the rule!

Comment: Which books? Which pages?

Comment: You work in the interaction picture because you are interested performing perturbation theory with respect to the interaction. The physics can not depend on the "picture" you use to do the calculation, so there is likely some hard-to-see problem with your derivation, or some hard-to-notice thing you are implicitly assuming that turns out to be false... thus, this is a "check-my-work" question and is off-topic.

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)#Time-dependent_perturbation_theory). Check your perturbation theory to first order. Your *c* s are very different!

Comment: Donald McQuarrie shows the golden rule using the Schrodinger picture in Physical Chemistry: A Molecular Approach.

Comment: You can't expect the first term of the series to work well if the terms depend on the full Hamiltonian. This approximate method is usually used for the perturbation Hamiltonian, which has to be in some sense small, so that the first approximation is accurate enough.

Comment: Using the full Hamiltonian, the higher order terms will likely contribute substantially.

Comment: Have you checked your procedure path with time-independent V, where you have the answer?

Comment: @JánLalinský The expansion parameter is t and t is small. The terms not considered in the expansion are terms of higher order in t. We do not need the Hamiltonian to be small if t is small. Am I right?

Comment: @hft I'm sorry if it appears so, but I'm not asking to look for my error. I'm pointing out that I cannot get why working in the interaction picture is essential to get the rule by simple calculations. In order to say that, you must show that you face difficulties when you try to work in different pictures.

Comment: @GrandeRocco Right. But for small enough $t$ your result is the same as the standard one. It seems your method works only for much shorter times where $e^{i(E_m-E_n)t/\hbar} \approx 1$ and $V_{mn}(0)$ is non-zero.

Comment: @CosmasZachos yes I did. With a time independent V I get a transition probability $\sim t^2$ instead of $\sim t\delta(E_n−E_m)$.

Comment: Sakurai & Napolitano (5.281). Explain.  Trying it on a 2-state system should clarify your misreading of the literature!